# Does jsdom support function fetch when parsing string or loading urls in nested <script> tags?

Tags: javascript, node.js, javascript-objects, jsdom

Probably a very beginner question as I am a just learning.  I'm using a windows 10 Nodejs latest distribution as well as a 512 Meg tiny core 32 virtual box distribution.

The ultimate goal is to read from a web site, programmatically navigate to a page that's live and display on a memory limited Raspberry Pi Zero w 2 and show a small subset of the page functionally while being booted being totally in memory. The underpowered device was selected for price, can be powered by a tv usb port, and small form factor. Everything must be in memory after boot because tv may be turned off at any time. jsdom/nodejs/ricore/epiphany seems to work in theory.

Problem.. fetch which is embeded in the website does not work.

Created a directory and have run the following commands to setup (in git bash).

```
npm init
npm i jsdom node-fetch
```

This is Simple code illustrating the problem:

```js
import { JSDOM } from "jsdom";
import fetch from "node-fetch";
globalThis.fetch = fetch;


const dom = new JSDOM(`

<script>fetch("http://google.com")</script>`,
{
    resources:"usable",
    runScripts:"dangerously"
});
```

My understanding is the node does not support fetch API out the box hence the import from node-fetch. jsdom/Nodejs is doing the fetching whenever the JavaScript is doing an implicit fetch. However, when passed into the JSDOM constructor, within the source string or even nested files within that were implicitly fetched within any JavaScript file, explicit fetch is not supported.

My understanding is a normal browser would support the fetch call without any added support. Questions:

- Is there anything else that needs to be enabled as this seems to be
  very basic?
- Are there any other functions within the sandbox which
  will have a similar effect (this is my first hurdle) which need to be polyfilled?

Here is the error when run...

```
Error: Uncaught [ReferenceError: fetch is not defined]
    at reportException (...\test\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\helpers\runtime-script-errors.js:66:24)
    at processJavaScript (...\test\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\nodes\HTMLScriptElement-impl.js:243:7)
    at HTMLScriptElementImpl._innerEval (...\test\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\nodes\HTMLScriptElement-impl.js:176:5)
    at ...\test\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\nodes\HTMLScriptElement-impl.js:115:12
    at ResourceQueue.push (...\test\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\browser\resources\resource-queue.js:53:16)
    at HTMLScriptElementImpl._fetchInternalScript (...\test\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\nodes\HTMLScriptElement-impl.js:114:21)
    at HTMLScriptElementImpl._eval (...\test\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\nodes\HTMLScriptElement-impl.js:170:12)
    at HTMLScriptElementImpl._poppedOffStackOfOpenElements (...\test\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\nodes\HTMLScriptElement-impl.js:133:10)
    at OpenElementStack.pop (...\test\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\browser\parser\html.js:44:12)
    at Object.endTagInText [as END_TAG_TOKEN] (...\test\node_modules\parse5\lib\parser\index.js:2153:20) ReferenceError: fetch is not defined
    at about:blank:1:1
    at Script.runInContext (node:vm:139:12)
    at Object.runInContext (node:vm:289:6)
    at processJavaScript (...\test\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\nodes\HTMLScriptElement-impl.js:241:10)
    at HTMLScriptElementImpl._innerEval (...\test\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\nodes\HTMLScriptElement-impl.js:176:5)
    at ...\test\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\nodes\HTMLScriptElement-impl.js:115:12
    at ResourceQueue.push (...\test\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\browser\resources\resource-queue.js:53:16)
    at HTMLScriptElementImpl._fetchInternalScript (...\test\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\nodes\HTMLScriptElement-impl.js:114:21)
    at HTMLScriptElementImpl._eval (...\test\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\nodes\HTMLScriptElement-impl.js:170:12)
    at HTMLScriptElementImpl._poppedOffStackOfOpenElements (...\test\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\nodes\HTMLScriptElement-impl.js:133:10)
```

Comment: I would say that jsdom is the wrong tool for the job. If you need a browser environment, use a browser. Tools like Puppeteer provide the executable with the install and you get a headless version of Chromium to go with it.

Comment: I actually went this route and made headway.  The problem is that I will be ultimately running this on a Raspberry pi zero w 2 (when I get my hands on it) using picore.  The puppeteer footprint was easily almost 850Meg minimum even before I started my code to extract. Rpi hw is only 512 Meg and everything needs to fit in ram. jsdom and a minimal browser will fit the bill to display a scaled down version of the live site of a particular page if it works. (Once booted, the disk should be unmounted and everything will run from memory.)

Comment: To further clarify, the dom extraction is for a memory and performance efficient way to build a webpage on the fly for  extracting a small portion of the original of what I am using for display on the web browser, kept up to date real time. If you have a efficient way of doing this, please say so. @HereticMonkey

Comment: Correction (could not edit my response): Wanted to run everything in qemu but its beyond my skillset. Tested on win10 and tinycore 512 Meg vbox to sim rpicore. In Windows 10, Puppeteer good on win10.  However, puppeteer doesnt run on tinycore with autodownload nor manually set old os chromium. The 850 Meg min I referred to was selenium with firefox (geicko driver) run on tinycore. (I temporarily chged the vm to 1 Gig ) VM not desired as its too much load & want all in mem. In the original question the same error occurs in win10 and the 512 tiny core vm, so it seems to be a dsdom/node problem.

Answer (score 2):

**JSDOM** does not include **Fetch** by default. 
**JSDOM** is a headless browser that runs on **node**, and the `node-fetch` package is a polyfill for adding **Fetch** to **node** but not to **JSDOM.**

Instead, you need the `whatwg-fetch` polyfill:
https://github.com/github/fetch

```
npm install whatwg-fetch
```

Then load the polyfill script into **JSDOM**:

```js
import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom';
import fs from 'fs';

const dom = new JSDOM('', { runScripts: 'outside-only' });
const fetchPkg = 'node_modules/whatwg-fetch/dist/fetch.umd.js';
dom.window.eval(fs.readFileSync(fetchPkg, 'utf-8'));
```

Here's a full example on GitHub I created for a **mocha** test that loads an array of scripts and also includes the `VirtualConsole` to capture `console.log` output:
[spec/jsdom.spec.js](https://github.com/center-key/fetch-json/blob/main/spec/jsdom.spec.js)

Comment: Hi Dem, thanks for sharing. I'm looking through a typical create react app, and the jsdom seems to be set up out of the box. Where should I write the code block you used above to inject whatwg-fetch? Thanks again :)